# Signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Tags: java, gwt, maven

class "org.mortbay.util.DateCache"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

I am working on GWT and maven. My GWT code is in project2. It works fine when I run it alone but when I try to create a dependency on another project, I get this error. I also searched on google for the solution. What I got is that classes belonging to the same package are loaded from different JAR files. But I have no clue on how to make sure that they have the same certificate. Is there any way that I could get rid of this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your objects static and singleton, and load them on start up, so that whenever a new jar tries to initiate it, it will always return the same object. I know that some work should be done here, but you need it!

Comment: I still don't get your suggestion. The problem is that I don't know what classes are loaded from different packages. Did I misunderstand your solution? Is there any way that I can check the certificate of the packages?

Comment: org.mortbay.util.DateCache: the objects of this class

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem and I solved it by following these instructions:

"make sure that hamcrest.jar is before the JUnit library included by Eclipse in the classpath."